# Express Swagger Generator - defined object array inside formdata

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I am creating API documentation for nodejs express app using express-swagger-generator. I use this code to add API for endpoint

```
* @route POST /soals
* @group Soal
* @consumes multipart/form-data
* @param {string} soals.formData.required - soal
* @param {integer} id_type.formData.required - id type soal
* @param {integer} id_matpel.formData.required - id matpel
* @param {string} jawaban.formData.required - jawab
* @param {file} picture.formData.required - pembahasan
* @returns {object} 200 - Success
* @returns {object} 400 - Error
```

how i can add my model into it

```
 * @typedef Choice
 * @property {string} value.required
 * @property {integer} isTrue.required
```

Answer (score 0):

- @param {Choice.model} Choice.body.required - some explanation

Then also in the model you can add a dash and some text as explanation for the properties ex:

- @typedef Choice
- @property {string} value.required - this is a value
- @property {integer} isTrue.required - this is a boolean